# Entity Framework - Problem with querying nullable column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a problem querying data from a table with a nullable tinyint column.
The problem seems to be that the query is generated as:

```
AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[PositionEffect] AS int) = @p__linq__3)
```

=> @p__linq__3 = NULL

If i run that query manually it doesn't turn up any results. However, when I replace the query with:

```
AND ([Extent1].[PositionEffect] IS @p__linq__3)
```

it turns up the expected results.
My C# query looks like this:

```
 context.Allocations.Where(x => ... && x.PositionEffect == (byte?) positionEffect)
```

So, why is the entity framework generating the incorrect query here and is there any way to fix this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Does this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d00f5611-4fce-4da4-8f79-802336fdfe1a/ shed any light on the issue?

Comment: thanks, yes this did help, though it was for linq to sql and not entity framework (object.Equals does not work in entity framework) and I had to resort to this nasty piece of code:  (positionEffect == null ? x.PositionEffect == null : x.PositionEffect == (byte?)positionEffect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Will A pointed out, this seems to be a reported bug in Entity Framework and the workaround to generate the correct query is:

```
 (positionEffect == null ? x.PositionEffect == null : x.PositionEffect == (byte?)positionEffect)
```