# Why null and reference to null not the same thing

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, null, nullable

Why these two methods work differently:

```
    public List<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        int? parentId = null;
        var l = _dataContext.Foos.Where(x => x.ParentElementId == parentId).ToList();
        return l;
    }

    public List<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        var l = _dataContext.Foos.Where(x => x.ParentElementId == null).ToList();
        return l;
    }
```

The first one returns nothing. Second returns what was expected. Data comes from EF. `ParentElementId` is nullable.

Comment: This has been asked on SO within the past month. I can't remember what the resolution was or what the exact question was, but it does exist.

Comment: @pst knowing that, helps a lot... it is really a relieve...

Comment: For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205238/entity-framework-problem-with-querying-nullable-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you can't compare to null in SQL, it has the special `IS NULL` operator to check for null values.

The first query will be translated into a comparison, where the parameter is null:

```
WHERE ParentElementId = @param
```

This doesn't work, because comparing two null values doesn't yield true.

The second query will be translated into a null check, because the null value is a constant:

```
WHERE ParentElementId IS NULL
```

This works because EF is not fooled to translate it into a comparison.

Comment: Well done! Once again, you showed me how important is to look sometimes into sql profiler window. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a preferred work-about then for getting the `IS NULL` off a Nullable-null?

Answer (score 2):

I know, you got your answer but here is some additional insight:

- This issue has been discussed on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d00f5611-4fce-4da4-8f79-802336fdfe1a/). Some people believe it's a bug, others say this is intentional behaviour due to performance reasons
- It's always helps running [EFProf](http://efprof.com/) or Sql Server Profiler (in case you are working with SQL Server. For example your two examples translate into two following statements respectively:

  ```
  SELECT 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[ParentElementId] AS [ParentElementId]
  FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE [Extent1].[ParentElementId] = NULL

  SELECT 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[ParentElementId] AS [ParentElementId]
  FROM [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE [Extent1].[ParentElementId] IS NULL
  ```

This technique (looking at generated SQL) is often very useful when dealing with problems in EF.

Comment: thank you... I've never heard about EFProf. Gotta try that... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Captain Obvious: because `parentId` is not `null`, probably.

**Response to edit**: first one is not compilable. Type cannot be infered for null.

**Response to another edit**: Because EF query translates nullable types incorrectly probably

Comment: They are `null` in both cases. The difference is the type in the first is `== (int?)null` (from `== parentId`, where `int? parentId = null`) and the type in the second is `== (object)null`. However, then this goes in through all the magic -- where the Expression tree is inspected -- and something causes the behavior to differ.

Comment: >EF query translates nullable types incorrectly.
 What do you mean?

Comment: @Agzam, EF translates your code into SQL, you can trace the queries executed by EF and find the differences. Probably *Guffa* is correct and EF translates first one into comparison (which doesn't work) with nulls and second one into `is null`. Check the actual SQL queries generated by EF.